# how do I optimize chef recipe code

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, recipe

What the below code is basically doing is:

1. Checks to make sure the naemonstats-2-graphite.pl script exist on
   the system
2. Checks to make sure the collectd package is installed on the system
3. If 1 and 2 checks out OK, check to see if a collectd entry already
   exist in root’s crontab and if so, checks to see if it is commented
   out

This does a few things:

- ensures numerous entries are not added to cron whenever a collectd
  cron job is commented out
- ensures when the collectd cron job
  is commented out, it adds it back to cron Uncommented
- ensures when the collectd cron job does not exist at all in cron, it
  adds it, provided of course that 1 and 2 above checks out OK.

I need to avoid calling system utilities (if possible) and basically optimize this code. make it shorter.

my Chef Client, version = 12.19.36

```
CollectdCronCheck = system 'crontab -l | egrep "^#*/1.*naemonstats-2-graphite.pl.nc.-U./var/run/collectd-unixsock"'
if !CollectdCronCheck.nil?
    Chef::Log.info("########   I see that the cron entry for naemonstats collectd is commented out in root crontab - im fixing it now...   #########")
    cron "naemonstats-2-graphite" do
       minute '/1'
       command "#{node['naemon']['plugin_dir']}/server/scripts/cron/naemonstats-2-graphite.pl | nc -U /var/run/collectd-unixsock >& /dev/null"
    end
else
    cron "naemonstats-2-graphite" do
       minute '*/1'
       command "#{node['naemon']['plugin_dir']}/server/scripts/cron/naemonstats-2-graphite.pl | nc -U /var/run/collectd-unixsock >& /dev/null"
       only_if { File.exist?("#{node['naemon']['plugin_dir']}/server/scripts/cron/naemonstats-2-graphite.pl") && "rpm -qa | grep 'collectd'" }
       not_if "crontab -l | egrep '^*/1.*naemonstats-2-graphite.pl.nc.-U.*/var/run/collectd-unixsock'"
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing so many checks yourself? The `cron` resource is already idempotent itself. We generally recommend the `cron_d` resource from the `cron` cookbook instead of the core resource, but either way trust in Chef resources to be idempotent unless they say otherwise.

Comment: im very open to corrections.  im new to chef.  the reason the code looks the way it does right now is because the original way it was set up, was lacking.  meaning, if someone commented out the entry from cron, and then ran chef client, chef-client would add a new uncommented entry back to cron. which is ok. thats is good.  but, if the entry is commented out often from cron for testing purposes, chef-client will keep adding more entries to cron, without removing the existing entries that were commented out. i just want to avoid that.  or maybe im just not thinking of this properly.

Comment: Yeah, that's a downside of the `cron` resource in Chef core and is part of why we recommend the `cron_d` resource instead. It's a little more complex since you have to depend on a community cookbook (https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/cron#cron_d) but it doesn't have that "idempotent but non-convergent" problem. If you've not worked with community cookbooks before, jump on our community Slack team and someone can help you out with the basics.